# How to run a function every time another functions's output changes?

Tags: javascript, webview, app-inventor

I'm trying to make a WebView interface for an App Inventor app (but this is NOT an App Inventor question), but I need to make the JavaScript in the WebView run a function every time App Inventor changes the web view string.

Unfortunately, App Inventor makes the web view string a function, not a variable, so an object.watch shim won't work.

I need it to be two-way communication between App Inventor and the JS in the WebView.

Comment: And there is no event triggered ?

Comment: @JonasWilms Not that I know of.

Comment: [How does the property Webviewer.WebViewString work?](https://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#2webviewstring) would reloading the webpage from App Inventor be a possibility for you? See the example snippet...

Comment: @Taifun Not really, because the page is the app's UI.